# The usage of "dabbler": when a long-time dabbler who is defined as a short-time activist

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> I've been brooding over Buddhism lately, for several reasons. First, I
> read that Steve Jobs was **a long-time dabbler** in Buddhism and was even
> married in a Buddhist ceremony.
> [Source: Scientific American](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/why-i-dont-dig-buddhism/)

What is a dabbbler? Cambridge Dictionary defines it as "someone who takes a slight and not very serious interest in a subject, or tries a particular activity for a short period".

So it sounds odd to use the adjective "long-time" to modify "dabbler" who just tries an activity for a short period".

So how should I understand "Jobs was **a long-time dabbler** in Buddhism " properly? Does it mean "though Jobs had a long-time interest in Buddhism, he did't take Buddhism seriously"?  It is still  odd to me since he held his wedding ceremony in Buddhist way and you know a wedding ceremony is a serious event in life.

So, what is the proper manner to exactly understand the meaning of  "a long-time dabbler"?

Comment: You missed the word "or" in the definition you quote. It means "someone who takes a slight and not very serious interest in a subject" **or** someone who "tries a particular activity for a short period". If the latter does not apply, then the meaning is the former.

Comment: He repeatedly showed a desultory interest in Buddhism over many years. Having a Buddhist wedding might just be an example of relatively meaningless "showmanship". Lots of Brits get married in a Christian church despite having minimal interest in the actual religion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs is called a dabbler in the sense that he has a shallow grasp of Buddhism, following the letter rather than the spirit of the law.